# Image binding two way mode not working wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

i have an image tag in my window, whenever i am binding it in one way mode, its working fine, but unable to two way mode.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="sm.admno"  Grid.Row="0" Name="txtadm" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEditable="True"/>
<Image Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0"  Source="{Binding ElementName=txtadm, Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedItem.sp.pic, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="imgpic"/>
```

class i am using

```
public string admno { get; set; }
public byte[] pic { get; set; }
```

data binding souce

```
var dt = from sm in db.studentmains
         join sp in db.StudentPersonals on sm.admno equals sp.admno
         select new { sm, sp};
txtadm.ItemsSource = dt.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Image.Source` is not a property for which `TwoWay` makes any sense, the control is not interactive, it's not going to change the source. If you modify it, you should modify the data, not the `Image.Source`.

Comment: how can i? can you tell me please?

Comment: @jammyhunt: can what?